# How to consume Soap Web Service in sencha touch 2?

Tags: web-services, extjs, soap, touch

I'm new in sencha touch and I want consuming a SOAP WS like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <register_user soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <a xsi:type="xsd:string">?</a>
         <b xsi:type="xsd:string">?</b>
         <c xsi:type="xsd:string">?</c>
         <d xsi:type="xsd:string">?</d>
      </register_user>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This aplication will be a hybrid aplication in android,
Help! please.

Answer (score 0):

You could populate your stores in the application by doing something like this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'MyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'myURL',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    listeners: {

        //[...]

    }
});
```

Please see [Ext.data.Store](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) for more information. You can also see [Ext.data.RestProxy](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) for CRUD actions.

Hope it helps!